# Create list of pair of values 0 to n-1 in lexicographical order

Tags: list, prolog

I'm doing a program with Result is a pair of values [X,Y] between 0 and N-1 in lexicographic order

I have this right now:

```
pairs(N,R) :-
   pairsHelp(N,R,0,0).

pairsHelp(N,[],N,N) :- !.
pairsHelp(N,[],N,0) :- !.
pairsHelp(N,[[X,Y]|List],X,Y) :-
    Y is N-1,
    X < N,
    X1 is X + 1,
    pairsHelp(N,List,X1,0).
pairsHelp(N,[[X,Y]|List],X,Y) :-
    Y < N,
    Y1 is Y + 1,
    pairsHelp(N,List,X,Y1).
```

I'm getting what I want the first iteration but Prolog keeps going and then gives me a second answer.

```
?-pairs(2,R).
R = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] ;
false.
```

I don't want the second answer (false), just the first. I want it to stop after it finds the answer. Any ideas?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31164078/772868) for the `false`. It's completely harmless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that there is a *much* easier way to get what you are after. If indeed both X and Y are supposed to be integers, use `between/3` to enumerate integers ("lexicographical" here is the same as the order of natural numbers: 0, 1, 2, .... This is the order in which `between/3` will enumerate possible solutions if the third argument is a variable):

```
pairs(N, R) :-
    succ(N0, N),
    bagof(P, pair(N0, P), R).

pair(N0, X-Y) :-
    between(0, N0, X),
    between(0, N0, Y).
```

And then:

```
?- pairs(2, R).
R = [0-0, 0-1, 1-0, 1-1].

?- pairs(3, R).
R = [0-0, 0-1, 0-2, 1-0, 1-1, 1-2, 2-0, 2-1, ... - ...].
```

I am using the conventional Prolog way of representing a pair, `X-Y` (in canonical form: `-(X, Y)`) instead of `[X,Y]` (canonical form: `.(X, .(Y, []))`).

The good thing about this program is that you can easily re-write it to work with another "alphabet" of your choosing.

```
?- between(0, Upper, X).
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
x(0).
x(1).
% ...
x(Upper).

?- x(X).
```

For example, if we had an alphabet that consists of `b`, `a`, and `c` (in that order!):

```
foo(b).
foo(a).
foo(c).

foo_pairs(Ps) :-
    bagof(X-Y, ( foo(X), foo(Y) ), Ps).
```

and then:

```
?- foo_pairs(R).
R = [b-b, b-a, b-c, a-b, a-a, a-c, c-b, c-a, ... - ...].
```

The order of the clauses of `foo/1` defines the order of your alphabet. The conjunction `foo(X), foo(Y)` together with the order of `X-Y` in the pair defines the order of pairs in the list. Try writing for example `bagof(X-Y, ( foo(Y), foo(X) ), Ps)` to see what will be the order of pairs in `Ps`.

Answer (score 2):

**Use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)** in combination with [lambda](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord)!

```
?- use_module(library(lambda)).
```

In combination with [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`init0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047316/4609915) and
[`xproduct//2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30328630/4609915) ("cross product") simply write:

```
?- init0(=,3,Xs), phrase(xproduct(\X^Y^phrase([X-Y]),Xs),Pss).
Xs = [0,1,2], Pss = [0-0,0-1,0-2,1-0,1-1,1-2,2-0,2-1,2-2].
```

How about something *a little* more general? What about other values of `N`?

```
?- init0(=,N,Xs), phrase(xproduct(\X^Y^phrase([X-Y]),Xs),Pss).
  N = 0, Xs = [],          Pss = []
; N = 1, Xs = [0],         Pss = [0-0]
; N = 2, Xs = [0,1],       Pss = [0-0,0-1,
                                  1-0,1-1]
; N = 3, Xs = [0,1,2],     Pss = [0-0,0-1,0-2,
                                  1-0,1-1,1-2,
                                  2-0,2-1,2-2]
; N = 4, Xs = [0,1,2,3],   Pss = [0-0,0-1,0-2,0-3,
                                  1-0,1-1,1-2,1-3,
                                  2-0,2-1,2-2,2-3,
                                  3-0,3-1,3-2,3-3] 
; N = 5, Xs = [0,1,2,3,4], Pss = [0-0,0-1,0-2,0-3,0-4,
                                  1-0,1-1,1-2,1-3,1-4,
                                  2-0,2-1,2-2,2-3,2-4,
                                  3-0,3-1,3-2,3-3,3-4,
                                  4-0,4-1,4-2,4-3,4-4]
...
```

Does it work for other terms, too? What about order? Consider a case @Boris used in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31514652/4609915):

```
?- phrase(xproduct(\X^Y^phrase([X-Y]),[b,a,c]),Pss).
Pss = [b-b,b-a,b-c,a-b,a-a,a-c,c-b,c-a,c-c].  % succeeds deterministically
```